# How to import lesshat into every compiled .less file

Tags: gruntjs, less, grunt-contrib-less, lesshat

In grunt-contrib-stylus there is a import option:

import

Type: Array

Import given stylus packages into every compiled .styl file, as if you wrote '@import '...' in every single one of said files.

```
options: {
            compress: false,
            use: [ require('kouto-swiss') ],
            import: [ 'kouto-swiss' ]
         },
```

How can I do the same thing with lesshat in grunt-contrib-less ?

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK there's no native way to do this with `lessc`/`grunt-contrib-less`. (So you'd need some hack like for example simply concatenating/injecting `@import "your-file-of-interest";`" string/file into every less file by a separate Grunt task).

Comment: see: https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2402

Answer (score 1):

Since release 2 you can create plugins for Less easily. Thanks to [Implementing preprocessing plugins](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2429) you can create preprocess plugins too.

The preprocess plugin enable you to inject Less code before processing:

```
 LesshatProcessor.prototype = {
            process : function (src, extra) {
            var injected = '@import "' + path.resolve(__dirname, '../') + '/node_modules/lesshat/build/lesshat.less";\n';
            var ignored = extra.imports.contentsIgnoredChars;
            var fileInfo = extra.fileInfo;
            ignored[fileInfo.filename] = ignored[fileInfo.filename] || 0;
            ignored[fileInfo.filename] += injected.length;
            return injected + src;
            }
};
```

I have created a Lesshat plugin already: https://github.com/bassjobsen/less-plugin-lesshat. After installing this plugin by running `npm install less-plugin-lesshat` and then your are able to run: `lessc file.less --lesshat`.

You can also use this plugin together with grunt-contrib-less:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    less: {

        options: {
           plugins: [
                new (require('less-plugin-lesshat'))()
            ]
       },
        files: {'css/test.css' : 'less/test.less'}
      }
)};
```

Notice that you should install the latest version of Less with grunt-contrib-less until Less has [updated the version number](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2432) (and grunt-contrib-less uses that version).

To use the plugin now:

1. run `npm install grunt-contrib-less`
2. Navigate to `node_modules/grunt-contrib-less/`
3. Remove `node_modules/less`
4. Download and unzip the latest version of Less at https://github.com/less/less.js/archive/master.zip
5. run `npm install ./less.js`